# What does >& mean?

Tags: bash, io, file-descriptor, io-redirection

I was a little confused by this expression:

```
gcc -c -g program.c >& compiler.txt
```

I know `&>filename` will redirect both stdout and stderr to file `filename`.  But in this case the ampersand is **after** the greater than sign.  It looks like it's of the form `M>&N`, where `M` and `N` are file descriptors.

In the snippet above, do `M=1` and `N='compiler.txt'`?  How exactly is this different from:

```
gcc -c -g program.c > compiler.txt     (ampersand removed)
```

My understanding is that each open file is associated with a file descriptor greater than 2.  Is this correct?

If so, is a file name interchangeable with its file descriptor as the target of redirection?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This is the same as `&>`. From the bash manpage:

> Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error
>       This construct allows both the standard output (file descriptor 1)  and
>       the  standard  error output (file descriptor 2) to be redirected to the
>       file whose name is the expansion of word.
>
> ```
> There are two formats for  redirecting  standard  output  and  standard
> error:
>
>        &>word
> and
>        >&word
>
> Of the two forms, the first is preferred.  This is semantically equiva-
> lent to
>
>        >word 2>&1
> ```

Comment: I feel foolish.  I spent a bunch of time reading other sources and it was right there in the manpage.

Comment: It goes on to say "Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to `>word 2>&1`"

Comment: `>&` is the syntax used by csh and tcsh to redirect both stdout and stderr. That's probably why bash accepts it.

Comment: Does this mean that `&>word` and `>word 2>&1` are semantically equivalent?  The antecedent to "This" is not clear to me.

Comment: @geneorama yes, that is the case. "This" in the post was referring to `>& word` though.

Comment: Ah, `&>word` and `>word` are *nearly* the same because both standard out and standard error are redirected to word. However `&>word` and `>word 2>&1` are *exactly* the same because of how they will be written to the console.

Comment: @geneorama `&>word`, `>word 2>&1`, *and* `>&word` are exactly the same.

Comment: @jordanm I was trying to point out that `>word` is different from the others.  In fact, I think that `>word`, `1>word`, and `1>word2>2` are all exactly the same.

Comment: Now I realize that I made a mistake before based on what I read elsewhere. `>` only redirects standard out.  `>` does not redirect error. (I should probably redirect my future comments to `/dev/null`)

Comment: what does "&" do here?

Comment: @MichaelWang Nothing on it's own. it's part of the `&>` and `>&` syntaxes.

Answer (score 27):

### `&>` vs `>&`: the preferred version is `&>` (clobber)

Regarding:

- `&>`
- `>&`

both will clobber the file - truncate the file to 0 bytes before writing to it, just like `> file` would do in the STDIN-only case.

**However**, the [`bash` manual Redirections section](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) adds that:

> Of the two forms, the first is preferred. This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >word 2>&1
> ```
>
> When using the second form, *word* may not expand to a number or `-`. If it does, other redirection operators apply (see Duplicating File Descriptors below) for compatibility reasons.

(Note: [in `zsh` both are equivalent](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Redirection.html).)

It's very good practice to train your fingers to use the first (`&>`) form, because:

### Use `&>>` as `>>&` is not supported by `bash` (append)

There's only one append form:

> The format for appending standard output and standard error is:
>
> ```
> &>>word
> ```
>
> This is semantically equivalent to
>
> ```
> >>word 2>&1
> ```
>
> (see Duplicating File Descriptors below).

Note:

- The clobber usage of `&>` over `>&` in the section above is again recommended given that there is only one way for appending in `bash`.
- `zsh` allows both `&>>` and `>>&` forms.

Comment: so is `&` a special character that gets converted to 1 and 2 by the shell interpreter?

Comment: @FakherMokadem Nope, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).

Answer (score 3):

Slightly off-topic, but this is why I stick to the long form like `>/dev/null 2>&1` all the time.
That is confusing enough for people who do it backwards in things like cron without adding >&, &>, >>&, &>>, ... on top of it.
I frequently need to add notes in `crontab -l` reminding people that "2>&1 > /dev/null" is not a best practice.

As long as you remember that any "final destination" is given first, then it should be the same syntax on any Unix or Unix-like system using any Bourne-like shell, appending or otherwise.
Plus, since `&>` is effectively a Bash-ism (may have originated in csh? don't recall, but it is not POSIX either way), it is not always supported on locked-down commercial UNIX systems.